# Python-Zstandard: how to resolve error:global name 'zstd' is not defined?

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to run the script in linux termianl using python 2.7.
I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main1.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "main1.py", line 25, in main
    ver = zstd.__version__;
NameError: global name 'zstd' is not defined
```

please check code and suggest the changes or any other way to run the script successfully.

```
# import zstd library for zstandard simple api access and Compress
import csv
import os
import time
import sys
import io
import random
import zlib
#import zstandard as zstd

from zstd import *

def main():

   #set path of INPUT FILE here
    path = 'sai.txt'
    fh_input = open(path, "rb")

    #determine size of input file
    sizeinfo_if = os.stat('sai.txt')
    print('Size of input file is :',sizeinfo_if.st_size,'Bytes')

    #make sure zstd is installed and running
    ver = zstd.__version__;
    print('Zstd version : ',ver)

    #File for already existing(or newly created ) output file where the compressed data needs to be written
    fh_output = open('output.txt','wb')

    #Zstd compressor object creation
    cctx = zstd.ZstdCompressor()
    initial_timestamp = time.time()

    #Get byte sized chucks from in File, compress and write to out file
    with open('sai.txt', 'rb') as fh_input:
      byte_chunk = fh_input.read(1)
      while byte_chunk:
        #bdata=bytes(str.encode(byte_chunk))
        compressed = cctx.compress(byte_chunk)
        with cctx.write_to(fh_output) as compressor:
          compressor.write(byte_chunk)
        byte_chunk = fh_input.read(1)
    end_timestamp = time.time()

    print('Time taken to compress:',end_timestamp - initial_timestamp)
    sizeinfo_of = os.stat('output.txt')
    print('Size of output File is:',sizeinfo_of.st_size,'Bytes')

    main()
```

Comment: uncomment the line 9 : `#import zstandard as zstd`

Comment: Or replace `from zstd import *` with `import zstd`

Comment: thank you for the suggestions they worked out. but in the results, the output file is larger than the original file. please check the code and suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me importing in the next way (python 3.8)

```
import zstd

print('Zstd version : ', zstd.version())
```